# How to fade to silence in Ableton Live?

Tags: ableton-live, automation

What is the recommended way to fade to silence in Ableton Live?

- Automation of Track Volume is not recommended, because you lose the
  ability to adjust the overall volume of the track.
- Automation of Utility Gain is not sufficient because it only allows attenuation to -35dB.
- Using fades does not apply to groups, master or return tracks.

Maybe automate the chain volume of an Audio Rack? What is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just fade the clip volume directly on your clip?!

[image: fadind clip volume]

(picture from http://www.kentsandvik.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Two instances (or more) of Utility to attenuate further.

Take two instances of utility. Select them both and hit ctrl+g to group them. Then take the gain knob on both an map them to the same macro knob. Close up the rack, and now you have a utility with -70db. Duplicate the utilities within the effect rack to get additional attenuation.

Then when your new effect rack has the desired level of attenuation, name it "silencer" and save it to your user library for future use :)

Comment: Actually, once you have an audio effect rack, you can just use the chain volume. I placed an instance of Utility in it to get a chain, mapped the chain volume to a macro control and automated that. As an added benefit, conversion from Track Volume automation can be done by copy & paste, because the ranges of both are the same (which is not the case for Utility Gain).

Comment: ^--- This!  This is the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the auto filter on the master track. automate that to silence.

Comment: I agree with this answer. The master track should ideally always be set to unity-gain/0dB so fading out the master track and resetting it to 0dB after the fade is complete. Otherwise (if you need to fade individual tracks for instance) then one should consider using a more advanced DAW.